# How to show 100% full sugarless function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, say `putStrLn "one" >> putStrLn "two"`. If I do `:info >>`, I see this:

```
type Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
class Applicative m => Monad m where
  ...
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixl 1 >>
```

I would like to see what the expression `putStrLn "one" >> putStrLn "two"` is, replacing `>>` with this definition. But not just for this function expression, but any function expression, how to find and print the sugarless version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(>>)` is a function, and functions generally aren't considered sugar, even if they're from typeclasses. But anyway, in the expression `putStrLn "one" >> putStrLn "two"`, it comes from the `IO` monad, so its definition will be inside of [`instance Monad IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1512). It happens to be `(*>)` which is itself `thenIO`, which is this:

```
thenIO :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b
thenIO (IO m) k = IO (\ s -> case m s of (# new_s, _ #) -> unIO k new_s)
```

Note that this uses parts of `IO` that aren't public API, so this isn't really something that you could write yourself in a normal program.